# $\infty-$groupoid of $A_{\infty}$ algebras

Tags: groupoids, ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

Hello,

Consider first the following $2-$groupoid of Algebras over $\mathbb{C}$.  Objects are Algebras, $1-$morphisms are isomorphisms, and a $2-$morphism between the isoms $f$ and $g$ from $A$ to $B$ is an element of $B^{\times}$ such that $f(a) b = b g(a)$ for all $a \in A$.

This is a certain sub$2$groupoid of the $2-$category of categories where the objects are the linear categories $A-$mod, the $1-$morphisms are (certain) functors (I think preserving the tensor structure), 
and the $2-$morphisms are natural transformations.  Alternatively, take linear categories with a point as object and morphisms $A$ and consider functors and natural tranformations of those.

Is there a natural analogue of this in the case of $A_{\infty}$ algebras?  I was hoping to understand some systematic way of writing down all the higher morphisms in an $\infty-$groupoid of $A_{\infty}$ algebras and hoping that they are all non-trivial.  However, I don't even understand the analogue of the elements $b$ from above.

Is this done in the literature somewhere where one can extract explicit formulae?  One guess would be to consider $A_{\infty}-$algebras as $A_{\infty}-$categories with one object, but this does not help unless one can explicitly write down some explicit $\infty-$groupoid structure on $A_{\infty}-$categories which I guess would require one to first convert these $A_{\infty}-$categories to $\infty-$categories

--Oren

Answer (score 8):

Notice that you are looking at the 2-category of algebras, bimodules and bimodule homomorphism.

Because of this: if you regard a morphism $f : A \to B$ of algebras as an $A$-$B$ bimodule $B_f$ ($B$ equipped with the obvious right $B$-action and with left $A$-action induced by $f$) then the 2-morphisms that you are looking at are bimodule homomorphism $B_g \to B_f$ given on $B$ by left multiplication with $b \in B$ (this trivially respects the right $B$-action and the equation $f(a)b = b g(a)$ is precisely the condition that it also respects the left $A$-action.)

So you are looking for the $A_\infty$-version of (the maximal higher groupoid inside) the 2-category of algebras, bimodules and bimodule homomorphisms.

Now, in

Berger, Moerdijk, *Resolution of coloured operads and rectification of homotopy algebras* http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/math/pdf/0512/0512576v2.pdf

there is described in section 6 a model-category theoretic construction of a simplicial category whose objects are $A_\infty$-algebras, morphisms are bimodules of $A_\infty$-algebras, 2-morphisms are bimodule homomorphisms, and so on.

This simplicial category you may think of as presenting an $\infty$-category of $A_\infty$-algebras.

(Notice that this applies to $A_\infty$-algebras over any suitable enriching category, say tor $A_\infty$-spaces You are probably thinking of the standard dg-case, enriched over chain complexes, to which it applies in particular.)

Some paragraphs on this you can also find here:

http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/model+structure+on+algebras+over+an+operad#InfCatOfMods

Comment: Excellent, I am especially eager to read about the "so on" part, thanks!  Yes, I was thinking of the dg enriched case  (although unfortunately when one considers curved $A_{\infty}$ algebras and curved morphisms its not quite that case anymore)

Although this could be related to the Seidel construction via reinterpreting $A_{\infty}-$cats as $\infty-$cats, that sounds like a difficult path, whereas Berger, Moerdijk sounds more directly related to what I need.

Comment: It seems that the first new feature that is present for $A_{\infty}$ algebras as opposed to regular algebras is that the bimodule homomorphisms themselves have non-identity morphisms between them, even when the bimodules come from algebra isomorphisms.  Do the bimodules between two $A_\infty$ algebras form a simplicial category in some standard way?  What are the morphisms between two isomorphisms $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ between the $A_{1}-A_{2}$ bimodules $B_{1}$ and $B_{2}$?  

Comment: You mean for a fixed pair of $A_\infty$-algebras, what's the $\infty$-category of bimodules betweem them? Recall from Berger-Moerdijk the strategy to get that: there is an operad whose algebas are bimodules. Pass to the correspnding model category of its homotopy algebras as described by Berger-Moerdijk. That presents the $\infty$-category of all $A_\infty$-bimodules. It comes with two functors to that of just $A_\infty$-algebras, so take the fiber over your chosen ones. ...

Comment: ... This is actually the precise way to get $\infty$-categories by presenting them by model categories. Regarding that simplicial category that we talked about as an $\infty$-category really requires a bit more discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Seidel's book *Fukaya categories and Picard-Lefschetz theory*, sections (1a-e), describes in explicit terms the $A_\infty$-category of non-unital functors between two fixed (small) $A_\infty$-categories, as well as the functors between functor-categories obtained by composing with a fixed functor on the left or right. This is not quite the whole story concerning composition.

Unsurprisingly, you can formulate everything as sums over trees, but the signs are nasty.

Comment: No need to climb higher: an $A_\infty$-category is already a model for a (stable) $\infty$-category.

Comment: Urs: thanks! I'll remove that sentence.

Comment: Thanks for this reference!   I also see that this issue was discussed over here:  http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2006/11/chernsimons_lie3algebra_inside.html#c006614.   There they discussed how to cook up a quasicategory of $L_{\infty}$ algebras and gave some references.  It would be great to even have some explicit understanding of what the invertible $2$ and $3-$morphisms look like, even in a case where $m_{4}$ and higher vanish for all the algebras involved.

Comment: Notice the difference between the oo-categories of homotopy algebras whose 1-morphisms are just plain morphisms and those where the 1-morphisms are more generally bimodules. For the first version a comprehensive construction and discussion of oo-categories of homotopy algebras over any suitable operad is at http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/model+structure+on+algebras+over+an+operad . In the Examples-section is discussed how to generalize this to $\infty$-categories whose 1-morphisms are allowed to be bimodules.