# homotopy transfer for sheaves of algebras

Tags: homotopy-theory, homological-algebra

**homotopy transfer for algebras**

Let $A$ be a differential graded (dg) $k$-algebra, and $H(A)$ its cohomology. $H(A)$ is naturally equipped with the structure of a graded algebra. In general we don't have that $H(A)$ and $A$ are weakly equivalent (i.e. quasi-isomorphic).

Nevertheless, it is well-known that there exists an $A_\infty$-algebra structure $(m_k)_{k\geq1}$ on $H(A)$ with the following properties:

- $H(A)$ equipped with this $A_\infty$-structure is weakly equivalent to $A$.
- the first structure map $m_1$ (i.e. the differential) vanishes.
- the second structure map $m_2$ coincide with the natural product on $H(A)$.

This structure is essentially unique: it is unique up to a unique $A_\infty$-isomorphism.

Moreover, there are explicit formulas for for the $A_\infty$-structure and the weak equivalence, in terms of planar trees. The main point is that the formula involves the choice of quasi-isomorphisms $i:H(A)\to A$ and $p:A\to H(A)$, together with an homotopy $h$ between $i\circ p$ and $id_A$.

**homotopy transfer for sheaves of dg algebras?**

I would be interested to know how to adapt this for sheaves. Namely, if now $A$ is a sheaf of dg algebras and $H(A)$ its cohomology sheaf. First of all one has to assume that $A$ is formal (i.e. quasi-isomorphic to $H(A)$) as a sheaf of $k$-modules. But even in this situation the existence of $i$, $p$ and $h$ is not guarantied.

**the question**

> How does homotopy transfer works for sheaves of algebras?

**possible (incomplete) answer**

One can do things locally and then try to glue, the gluing condition will probably be satisfied only in a weak sens... and then my question might boil down to

> what is the right definition of a (homotopy) sheaf of $A_\infty$-algeras?

A way to answer this is to use model categories. I was planning to proceed in the following way (very shortly): $A_\infty$-algebras are fibrant objects in the model category of dg coalgebras, then we have a Reedy model structure on presheaves of dg coalgebras, and sheaves of $A_\infty$-algebras can be defined as fibrant objects in this model category.

At this moment I am stuck. I am sure I am not far from the answer, but somehow I can't see the point.

Comment: It seems that what breaks is not the transference of $A_\infty$ structures, but earlier: quasi-isomorphisms need not have completions to homotopy equivalences when you do not have the axiom of choice at your disposal.  Certainly the formulae work whenever you do have a homotopy equivalence $i,p,h$ connecting $A$ with $H(A)$.

Comment: @Theo. Agreed. The point is that you do not always have $i$, $p$, $h$ connecting $A$ and $H(A)$. Bu still, there should be a way to transfer (actually this is exactly what the paper of Sagave mentioned by Fernando is about. 

Comment: @DamienC

Please let me know if you figure out this sheaf thing!  I was trying to get to the same issue at 
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/46373/infty-groupoid-of-a-infty-algebras

but I am still confused about it.  You once told me that maybe it should involve a simplicial category of cofibrant dg algebras.

Comment: I meant to say dg coalgebras.

Comment: Dear Oren, yes I think I figured it out. I'll post an answer to me own question about it as soon as possible. Best, Damien

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $R$ is a commutative $k$-algebra, a quasi-coherent sheaf of dg-$k$-algebras on $\operatorname{Spec}R$ would be just a dg-$R$-algebra $A$. It's known that there need not be any $R$-linear A-infinity structure on $H(A)$ quasi-isomorphic to $A$ in the $A$-infinity sense. Therefore the classical transfer theorem (which only works over fields) does not sheafify. Nevertheless, Sagave defined the notion of *derived A-infinity algebra* in such a way that there is a derived A-infinity structure on $H(A)$ quasi-isomorphic to $A$ in an $R$-linear and derived A-infinity sense, see :

MR2608191 (2011c:16030)
Sagave, Steffen(N-OSLO)
DG-algebras and derived -algebras. (English summary)
J. Reine Angew. Math. 639 (2010), 73–105.

This solves the case of quasi-coherent sheaves on affine schemes, so it could be a good starting point to answer your question...

Comment: @Fernando, Ok over a field one can always choose representatives of homology classes. But, if you are given a homotopy retract, then the transfer theorem works in any case, no matter the ground field being a field. 

Comment: @Bruno: you are right. But the point is precisely that you don't always have a homotopy retract in case you work with a ring k (or with sheaves). 

Comment: Hi Bruno! Nice to see you here :-)